# Securely handle data with sockets java

Tags: java, sockets

So I'm new to this socket/serversocket thing, and I'm wondering how I can securely send values of coins to give a player without them being able to simply edit it.

For example, I use my BufferedWriter and I want the player to receive int number of coins, so I use the output and send "give player 5 coins" or some message.  Someone could simply edit the code by decompiling and give themselves more using the code.  Is there any way around this that I can check to make sure its the correct value and not some value they put in themselves?

Comment: How does that user use the coins you sent to him? Does he use them at your server again, or he can exchange with other clients directly?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy A little bit of both, they can use the coins to trade with other players, in a sense, and they can use them to buy from the shop which is basically from the server.

Comment: If a centralized architecture is ok, then you can use your server as an entity that actually performs all the transfers between client's accounts. In such an architecture, you don't need to take into account what the client states about his balance: you (the server) just know the balance, so the problem goes away. If you need a decentralized architecture, then... how about a blockchain? :)

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I have no idea what either of those are, not to sound unthankful, but how would I have it so when the client does an action it adds the correct coins.

For example: Client clicks sell button and sells items, how would I then tell the server the amount of coins they are supposed to get without them being able to simply edit the string?

If you could provide an example that would be ideal, thank you!

Comment: Ok, the user clicks 'Sell' button, so he is supposed to get 10 coins. You update his account at your server and increment its balance with 10 coins, so now that user has 20 (before he had 10). You then write him 'you got 10 coins', but this is just an informational message. To spend those coins, he has to use your API, and your software behind the API knows that he only has 20 coins, so if he tries to spend 30, it will be rejected. In this situation it is not important whether he messes with protocol messages or not.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy the problem is in clicking the sell button.... When he clicks it, I have to send a message to the server to tell it he clicked it correct?  If so then couldn't he just send a different message by editing the code which will give him more coins?

Comment: @ZacharyWalensa, he can edit the message to change how many coins it tells the server to spend, but the server knows how may coins he actually has in his account, and it rejects attempts to spend more than that.

Comment: Right.  The server shouldn't trust the user to say how much money he has.  The server should know, on its own, how much money the user has.  The user just gets to say what he wants to do with it, and the server rejects attempts to spend more money than the user has.

Comment: @Wyzard ok, so I put a set limit on the server... but then what kind of message do I send to the server from the client? they could just change it to what I send through the other buttons.

Comment: If the user is allowed to send other messages, it doesn't really matter whether he does it by editing messages or by clicking other buttons.  As long as the server only accepts messages that the user is allowed to send, it doesn't matter how the message is created.

Comment: @Wyzard How can I make sure they are only allowed to send those messages?

Comment: I've said several times already: the server needs to know what the user is allowed to do.  It needs to know how many coins the user has, what kind of things he can spend them on, and any other information that's needed.  With that information, when the server receives a message from the user, it can check whether the message is allowed.